Where do I ask more general questions about (learning) programming?
I'm new to site and would like to ask about learning to code in general. I posed this question but was advised I posted it in the wrong place. I believe meta is where to ask about the site, though I'm still a little confused. I hope this is where I should ask about where to ask some other question. I know I'm probably using the site wrong but I'm trying to figure it out.
The question I'm looking to post

I would like to begin to learn coding. This community has already resolved so many questions I have had. It seems like a good place to stick around and learn.
If anyone has advice on learning, especially brute force learning methods, I would much appreciate them. I had one quarter length class on programming logic and design, 20 years ago, and that is the extent of my current knowledge. Not only language specific questions,but programming in general, nuts and bolts tips, anything and everything that would help someone go from zero to game dev.
I would like to focus on c# c++ python for gaming reasons. Cobal would be handy but I suppose there prolly aren't many resources for that.
Any advice on how/where/what to learn would be greatly appreciated.


It's spelled COBOL, and it would really only be handy if you're specifically looking to get a job maintaining decades-old programs in the financial sector. (This can pay very well, but it's very niche and it's not most people's idea of a good time, even among programmers.)


I know I'm probably using the site wrong but I'm trying to figure it out.

If you're hoping that someone can teach you directly on site, then yes - we don't offer that. Stack Exchange sites are not discussion forums; on a Q&A site we require a specific question, not an invitation to help solve a problem. Anything that requires communicating back and forth doesn't work. The comments aren't for having a discussion; they're for figuring out what the question is, or what might be missing or unclear in an answer.
If you're hoping that someone can find off-site resources for you, then yes - most Stack Exchange sites disallow this. There are a few sites specifically for recommendations - in particular, Software Recommendations and Hardware Recommendations, but neither of these would apply in your case.
But if you have a question about the learning process then you're in the right place. As already suggested, Computer Science Educators will accept questions about self-learning. However, you will need a specific question - "where do I start?" doesn't qualify. The Q&A format can offer excellent explanations of individual topics, and how-to guides for small, self-contained tasks - but it doesn't work for tutorials where the tutorial author is choosing a sequence of small tasks. (Stack Exchange users are allowed and encouraged to ask and answer their own questions to share knowledge - but it still needs to be one question at a time, and they're supposed to be the kind of small, self-contained things that someone else could find with careful use of a search engine.)
We can't make up your mind for you about "where to start", or find a path for you if you feel "lost". If you have those kinds of issues, you will probably find a traditional discussion forum more helpful. Of course, make sure to check their pinned thread first. The "where do I start?" type questions are the kind that a lot of people have, and none of those people are special, and experts will get tired of repeating their advice.

Thank you for your answer. I'm learning more about this site and it's communities and purposes as I go.

Since your question indicates to me that, to a large extent, you're asking about self-learning as opposed to taking formal classes, note that the Computer Science Educators (CSE) SE site has support related to this. In particular, there are currently 153 questions there which are tagged self-learning, with a tag description of

Questions regarding teaching a topic to yourself. Use this tag to ask about ways and methods of teaching which apply to teaching yourself.

However, before possibly posting there, especially for the first time, I suggest that you first familiarize yourself at least somewhat with the CSE site. For example, go through some of its Help Center, in particular the What topics can I ask about here? and What types of questions should I avoid asking? pages. In addition, also check on a few of the posts which use your appropriate tags, e.g., self-learning, to get a feel for how the questions are presented and received by the CSE community. Finally, please search for any duplicates before posting.

Thank you. I will most certainly take a look there, and see what I can discover on my own. I feel like my early questions aren't really on point with this site and site groups were intended, but people have still been kind enough to give wonderful and useful answers all the same. I'll shall endeavour to do better.

Stack Overflow has tag wikis for the most popular languages. They include pointers for learning resources. I.E.,



Language
Tag Wiki URL




C#
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info


C++
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/info


Python
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info



You might try asking "more general questions" related to programming in Stack Overflow Dicussions [Labs].
Related

Where to ask for general advice for young programmers?


It should maybe be added that discussions on SO is a mixed bag. Before using it, one might want to read a bit on it in order to test it.

Just to clarify - "Stack Overflow has tag wikis..." means "look at those tag wikis for resources," not "ask a question on Stack Overflow using that tag." This sort of question is generally off-topic for SO.
